# Inverted Model When Importing to Unity

Tags: modeling, import, unity

I am struggling to understand what is happening to this asset pack I have downloaded. I save the blender file and then import into unity but it seems to be inverted and the model looks see through. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

This is the asset pack I originally downloaded. https://hexagon6.itch.io/sci-fi-tower-defense-pack

[image: What the model should look like. (blender)]
[image: In unity.]

##EDIT##

I figured out the issue.

You need to ensure that this button is clicked and then select the dropdown arrow and enable "Backface Culling".

When you have done that you then select the mesh, press "tab", press "a", then press "shift + n" this should recalculate the faces and then the model displays correctly in unity.

[image: Options]

Comment: Link to source of information https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi5287fr4f1AhUB3KQKHb5rCYIQFnoECA4QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9iV9wnvpQ1U&usg=AOvVaw2vuRgA8O8PQuFx6IxmkmP8

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, it is better to post it as an answer to your question to help people who have the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable *Backface Culling* to view the model as in game engines like Unity...

- For *material/render preview* by enabling the option in the material settings:
  [image]
- For *solid view* by switching to to ensure that this button is clicked and then select the dropdown arrow and enable .

[image: Options]

When you have done that and see through some faces, it means the normals are facing the wrong way -  you then select the mesh, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, press  <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> this should recalculate the faces and then the model displays correctly with *Backface Culling* (and so it displays correctly in game engines like Unity).

[Youtube source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iV9wnvpQ1U)